# Is there anyway to count how many keys an array has in Php?

Tags: php, arrays, count, key

```
Array
    (
        [0] => 'hello'
        [1] => 'there'
        [2] => 
        [3] => 
        [4] => 3
    )

// how to  get the number 5?
```

Comment: I was looking at my own code wrong which made me think that count ignored null values.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)

```
$arr = Array
    (
        0 => 'hello',
        1 => 'there',
        2 => null,
        3 => null,
        4 => 3,
    );
var_dump(count($arr));
```

Output:

> int(5)

Comment: `count(array_keys($arr))` then perhaps?

Comment: In the sample, even if keys (2,3) are empty, count will still count them as they exists. `count($arr)` even if there `false`,`null`,`0`,`""` etc, aslong as they exists `count()` will add them up, As `MatTheCat` says, `echo count(array(1,null,null));` gives 3

Answer (score 4):

[count()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) or [sizeof](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sizeof.php)

Comment: that will ignore the values of null ;)

Comment: So why echo count(array(1,null,null)); gives me 3??

Answer (score 3):

Works for me w/ NULL

```
$array = array('hello', 'there', NULL, NULL, 3);

echo "<pre>".print_r($array, true)."</pre><br />";
echo "Count: ".count($array)."<br />";
```

output

```
Array
(
    [0] => hello
    [1] => there
    [2] => 
    [3] => 
    [4] => 3
)

Count: 5
```

A quick [Google search for PHP Array](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_array.asp) should pull up results of all the functions available

Answer (score 0):

Below code was tested with PHP 5.3.2. and the output was `int 5`.

```
$a = array(
    0 => 'hello',
    1 => 'there',
    2 => null,
    3 => null,
    4 => 3,
);

var_dump(count($a));
```

Can you please provide more information about `null` not being counted? An older version maybe? Or simply messing with the rest of us? :)

EDIT: well, posted wrong code :)

Answer (score 0):

```
echo count($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try something different you can also do it by getting the max array key and adding +1 to account for the first array starting with zero.

```
$count = max(array_keys($my_array))+1;
echo $count;
```